# ASP NET MVC application asks static 'Main' method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, program-entry-point

Building ASP NET Application I capture the following error:

```
Error   CS5001  Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [ProjectName]   [ProjectPath]\CSC   1   Active
```

Output type of the project is '*Windows Application*'. Default namespace and assembly name match the namespace through the application. And there's just one project in solution.

The whole problem started as soon as I created entities model (based on Northwind), made some relevant changes in controller and called to create a new view. The window I received informed me 
**"*There was an error running the selected code generator: 'There was an error getting the type [ProjectName].Models.Category'. Try rebuilding the project*". [ProjectName].Models contains public class '*Category*'.**

I suppose it is just the result of some error, not the error itself.

I changed namespace all over the application not long ago, so I assume this might be the problem and the compiler still requires some changes to be done. But looking through the whole solution I didn't find any notions of the old namespace.

My competency in ASP.NET MVC is far from brilliant, so please any ideas how to check, what I should examine, where I should look through and/or change are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, pity me. It should be "*Class Library*" type instead of "*Windows Application*". Simple mistake made me triplecheck almost all the application (and a relevant part of similar SO issues).

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct, so another users can skip this answer.